# How to add DataGridView column from 2nd table in datasource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2013, datasource

I'm creating a Forms project in VS2013. I added a DataGridView to my form and set a table "employees" as its datasource (the project's datasource is an .mdf file created in SSMS 2008 R2). One of the columns in the employees table is the department id.

Rather than display the department id, obviously I want to display the department name from the departments table.

All I see I can do by adding a new column is use the same table's columns.

I looked into using the database as the datasource, and then adding columns from the different tables, but that didn't seem like the right approach, either.

How do I do this? Is it possible with the dialogs/visual aids, or can it only be done in teh code?

Comment: If its a mdf you can query the results you need...

Comment: Basically you can translate your id... case when 1 admin when 2 toys and so on. This is a small example. Then return your query with what you queried in a table and set it as the datasource...

Comment: You can also add another column in code to the table but i dont recommend this, query and return what you need from your mdf file...

Comment: @eventide: Is your question answered? You did not mark an answer and did not write any comment how your answer is unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to translate your department id.

Have a look at this snippet:

```
    Dim cmbCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn() With {
        .HeaderText = "Department",
        .DataPropertyName = "DepartmentID",
        .Name = "Department",
        .DisplayMember = "DepartmentName",
        .ValueMember = "DepartmentID",
        .DataSource = myDepartmentDataTable,
        .DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing
    }

    myDGV.Columns.RemoveAt(departmentColumnIndex)
    myDGV.Columns.Insert(departmentColumnIndex, cmbCol)
```

To make this work, you need a `DataTable` with one column "DepartmentID" and another column "DepartmentName". Setting the display style to "Nothing" makes the column look like a normal text column instead of a combobox column. The last two lines remove the regular text column you get from your initial data and replace it with your new combobox column.

You can also accomplish this via the `DataGridView`'s columns property by adding all of your columns manually, including your combobox column.